# Why didn't Ultron attack the Hulk in Avengers Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, avengers-age-of-ultron

Ultron has had his fair share against the avengers fighting against Iron Man, Captain America, and Thor why didn't he fight against the hulk? Besides the hit that Banner gave him in the very end there was no clear cut engagement between the two. Ultron attacked Thor and claimed that he was bothering him in which the Hulk was doing the same thing if not much more. So why didn't Ultron attack the Hulk in the same way that he attacked Thor?

Comment: If I were him, I wouldn't attack the Hulk too

Comment: Why do you think he should attack the Hulk? As you said, he had his hands full, and as everyone knows, it wouldn't end well for him. Your implicit assumption that he should attack the Hulk makes much less sense than not attacking him.

Comment: Loki had warned Ultron to stay clear of The Hulk.

Comment: Ultron reasoned that he wouldn't like Hulk when Hulk was angry.

Comment: Ultron's Sentries were extensions of his own mind, so in a way, Ultron _was_ attacking Hulk, just not with his prime Vibranium body.